Debian 10 - Remove 2 different versions of PHP
I have a really screwed up Debian 10 system.  It has about 20 years worth of customer records I have been tasked with recovering.  I'm pretty sure the problem started, when someone upgraded it from Debian 9 to Debian 10.
Initially MYSQL was clobbered, but I finally installed MariaDB, and using the command line interface, I can see the needed databases.  Basically, any PHP program that needs MYSQL fails with some sort of error.  As an example, PHPMyAdmin gives a MYSQLI missing error, even though I've put a copy of mysqli.so in what seems like the right directory.
If I run phpinfo.php from a browser, it says the PHP version is 5.6.  If run 'php -v' from the command line, it says it is PHP 7.0. As I've not been able to fix this, I was thinking about removing both versions of PHP, and reinstalling the correct one for Debian 10.
Any ideas on how to do this ??  BTW, I'm working on a cloned copy of the entire hard drive, so I'm not too worried about screwing up big time with experiments.  As a last resort, I'll build up a new drive using Debian 12, and migrating the huge var/www folder.
TIA !!
As I said above, I've tried adding a mysqli.so file, in the EXTENSIONS_DIR that PHP thinks it is using, but then PHPMyAdmin throws a JSON missing error.  I believe the system is getting confused between the 2 different PHP installs.
EDIT: Forgot to mention, that PHP programs seem to work fine EXCEPT when they need a MYSQL function.  It's possible that it is MYSQL that needs to be completely removed and re-installed.  I do have backups of the data, so that might be the way to go, but so far, my attempts at re-connecting PHP and MYSQL have be unsuccessful.

What keeps you from removing these versions through apt, like you would uninstall all other packages? If this is not working, how did you install these packages otherwise?

I've not tried that, but that is the next step.  The real issue is that PHP does not know MYSQL is installed or MYSQL doesn't know PHP is installed.  It is the "connector" between those two, that doesn't work.  I'm assuming that is 'mysqli.so', which seems to be there, and in the right place.

"PHP does not know MYSQL is installed" - what does that mean? Why not install the extension that you need to connect from PHP code to a MySQL server? "MYSQL doesn't know PHP is installed" - it doesn't need to know that, as MySQL would never initiate a connection to PHP

I've tried every possible install of extensions and nothing worked.
BUT, what did work was remove mysql, install mariadb, and disable, enable the proper Apache2 mods.  Also, MOST important, was I installed a PHP "shim" to translate the old mysql functions to the newer mysqli functions.  There was something about the upgrade from Debian 9 to Debian 10 that clobbered the old mysql setup.
